# Генератор ключей на C# и Python

Tags: c#, python, криптография

Есть код на С#, генерирующий ключ:

```
private static byte[] GenerateKey(string pass, int keyBytes = 32)
{
    const int iterations = 300;
    var salt = new byte[] { 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };
    var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pass, salt, iterations);
    return keyGenerator.GetBytes(keyBytes);
}
```

Затем, получаю ключ в base64:

```
byte[] key = GenerateKey(pass);
b64Key = Convert.ToBase64String(key);
```

Переписываю на Python:

```
def get_key(rand_key, keyBytes=32):
    iterations = 300
    salt = bytes((20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90))
    derived_key = PBKDF2(rand_key, salt, iterations, keyBytes)
    return bytes(derived_key)
```

Получаю строку в base64:

```
key = get_key(random_string)
b64Key = base64.b64encode(key.decode('utf-8'))
```

Получаются ключи разной длины на выходе, хотя вроде бы в обеих функциях по умолчанию длина ключа 32. Возможно, как-то неверно переведён функционал с C# на Python?

**P.S.:** замена Rfc2898 на PBKDF2 произведена согласно этой статье: [PBKDF2 Python keys vs .NET Rfc2898](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168544/pbkdf2-python-keys-vs-net-rfc2898). Используемая версия Python: 2.7.5. Функция PBKDF2 импортирована таким способом:

```
from pbkdf2 import PBKDF2
```

Comment: из какого пакета `PBKDF2()` функция? На какой версии Питона код должен работать? Приведите примеры входных данных (`pass`) и соответствующий результат (`b64key`). Наличие вызовов `bytes(derived_key)`, `b64encode(key.decode())` указывают на возможные проблемы с пониманием как с двоичными данными работать в Питоне.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась путём обрезки ключа, генерируемого с помощью кода на Python:

```
def get_key(rand_key, keyBytes=32):
    iterations = 300
    salt = bytes((20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90))
    derived_key = PBKDF2(rand_key, salt, iterations, keyBytes)

    #Переводим в байты ключ
    byte_key = bytes(derived_key)
    #Берём первые 32 байта
    split_key = byte_key[0:32]
    return bytes(split_key)
```

Однако, возможно, это не лучшее решение и не единственное. Буду рад комментариям и другим способам решения.